# Can't post JSON files with iglob?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, glob

I am able to POST *one* json file by doing the following:

```
url = 'https://myWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext'
json_file = open("/Users/ME/folder/folder/folder/folder/test.json")

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json_file, headers=headers)
```

but when I try to loop through all json files in a directory using iglob:

```
url = 'https://myWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext'
json_files = glob.iglob("/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/folder/*.json")

for data in json_files:
    test = {'file': open(data)}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=test, headers=headers)
```

The server throws me some crazy errors, indicating that I am posting invalid JSON primitive. I am using the *exact* same json file for both methods but the second one fails, for some reason.

Comment: Did you try and *print* `json_files` and see if you are really opening the same files?

Comment: print json_files = "<generator object iglob at 0x1028b4fa0>" and print json_file = "<open file '/Users/ME/Documents/folder/folder/folder/test.json', mode 'r' at 0x1021c9660>"

Comment: I am not really sure what that means but I know they're the same file, just being accessed differently

Comment: `iglob()` returns a generator, producing filenames on demand as you loop over the object. `print list(json_files)` gives you a list of all matches instead. But it doesn't matter, I spotted the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* use a dictionary here:

```
for data in json_files:
    test = open(data)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=test, headers=headers)
```

When using anything other than a string or open file object for `data`, you end up posting a *`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`* content body as `requests` encodes the request body for you. You want to post just the contents of the file, as you want to send a `application/json` body instead.

Note that in your single file test, you did *not* use a dictionary either.

Preferably, use the open file as a context manager to make sure it is closed again:

```
for data in json_files:
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    with open(data) as test:
        r = requests.post(url, data=test, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. I was using dictionaries in a previous chunk of code I had, this time grabbing a bunch of ".txt" files instead of ".json" files. Is this dictionary syntax particular to the file extension, in anyway?

Comment: @user3175426: it is particular to the *content type* you want to send. If you give `data` anything other than a string, it'll encode it to a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string for you (what a browser does when you POST a form).

Comment: @user3175426: you are not, however, sending an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body. You are sending `application/json`, which happens to match the contents of your files.

Comment: @user3175426: if you wanted to POST `text/plain` then you also wouldn't encode the body.

Comment: I see. I'll be more careful about how I POST different file types in the future. Thanks a lot for your help! :)